# How to make alert always when tab closed or window is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is reference of w3schools https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onunload

Here is written It may not work always. is there a solution which always capture on window/tab close and promt are you sure you want to leave this page just like this website stackoverflow.com has. when you are writing a question and try to close tab or window, it prompts a message. I want just like that.

This is my code written in head script.

```
$(window).bind('beforeunload', function(){
   return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});
```

Comment: It will only be triggered when the page get the focus. So before closing it, click the page first.

Comment: I do have form, and I tried to modify it but no luck

Comment: I clicked on page as well no luck

Comment: Where is your `$(window)...` placed? And did you include jQuery from a CDN?

Comment: In head of the html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please make sure you have included jQuery from a CDN. And call `$(window)...` in `$(document).ready...`

Here is my test demo, and it works fine.

```
<script src="https://cdn.staticfile.org/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(window).bind('beforeunload', function () {
            return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
        });
    });
</script>
```

Comment: It does not work. Also `.bind` function is deprecated since jQuery 3.0

Answer (score 0):

I tried this and it is working https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onbeforeunload

```
<body onbeforeunload="return myFunction()">
<script>
function myFunction() {
  return "Write something here...";
}
</script>

</body>
```